# Creative destruction and quality-adjusted inflation rate.

Tags: macroeconomics, inflation, economic-growth

I'm reading [this article in VoxEU.or](http://voxeu.org/article/missing-growth)g, and there's the following paragraph:

> If the statistical office is correct to assume that the
>   quality-adjusted inflation rate is the same for creatively destroyed
>   products as for surviving incumbent products, then the market share of
>   surviving incumbent products should stay constant over time. If
>   instead the market share of these incumbent products shrinks
>   systematically over time, then the surviving subset of products must
>   have higher average inflation than creatively destroyed products. For
>   a given elasticity of substitution between products, the more the
>   market share shrinks for surviving products, the more the missing
>   growth.

From what I understood, since the entering products have a lower quality-adjusted price, and that's why they enter the market. I don't understand several things:

1) Why the «surviving subset of products must have higher average inflation than creatively destroyed products»? Do they mean by this sentence, that the the surviving products have higher quality-adjusted inflation than those which just entered? If so, I understand that this would be a sufficient condition for the creative destruction, however, I don't see how it's a necessary conditions, as it seems to be implied by the text.

2)Why «For a given elasticity of substitution between products, the more the market share shrinks for surviving products, the more the missing growth.»?

Any help would be appreciated.